# How is this simple transistor circuit suppose to work?

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics, transistor

I've tried to replicate this circuit today.

[image]

1. My motor is a computerfan, they apperntly don't need a flyback diode since there [are no brushes.](https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/anatomy-of-computer-fans/2/)
2. I used a 12V power source for my arduino and hooked it up via
   VIM.
3. I used the arduino ground as external power source.
4. I verified that the transistor worked as expected with a voltmeter.

Here is the transistor I used:[image]

As I understand this, the transistor is stimulated to "steal" electrons away from the motors circuit. But it seems connected to the base. Why would you do that?

Comment: Not all transistors have the same pinout. How do you know what transistor is used in that drawing?

Comment: An answer may be found here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TransistorMotorControl

Comment: The circuit might be totally wrong. Where does it come from?

Comment: It seems like it is wrong, it's from a magnetic stirrer tutorial https://www.hackster.io/jdale18/magnetic-stirrer-88e726

Comment: @Himmators Thanks. Google picture search could not find the original picture. They use a tip31a, which has the pin in BCE order and is for a maximum current of 3 amps, that is more than the 100 milliamps of the bc548. They have forgotten a resistor to the base of the transistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many bad schematics and pictures online, and these pictures are really bad.

Do not try to make that. You may damage the Arduino board and the transistor.

- Even the picture of the BC548 is wrong. The BC548 is always 
  called "BC548" and never "BC-548".
- The BC548 is not a good choice to drive a motor. It can only
  do 100 mA continuous.
- The DC barrel socket has plus and minus wrong connected. 
  The 12V plus is connected to the Arduino GND. 
  That is not okay.
- The transistor in the first picture is probably a 
  transistor with the pins in BCE order.
- A resistor is missing to the base of the transisor.
- Because of the missing resistor, the Arduino board
  can be damaged.
  When the breadboard has a bad connection to GND,
  the 12V can go to pin 9 of the Arduino board.

@Dorian, there are no mystical higher alien intelligent thoughts for that schematic. It is obvious a wrong circuit that is meant to drive a motor with PWM using a transistor.

And last but not least:
There are a few different types of computer fans. Some have a capacitor inside and some will only accept a PWM signal to a PWM input.
Are you sure that your fan is able to accept PWM for the 12V power?

Comment: Wow, I sure learned a lesson here! I have a basic fan witout a PWM input, so the plan is to regulate the speed of the fan by changing the voltage. I tried this with a powercube and it seems to work fine :)

Comment: @Himmators please tell us what you want to do so we can help. You can add that to your question. Do you have a mosfet? A diode is always good, even if it might seem that it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a circuit to monitor the power loss in the motor supply. If the motor is powered and the circuit is not interrupted then the collector will poll Arduino pin 9 to GND.